# Scaffolding on Rails 6.1 api based app with versioning on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am learning to build a Rails API app with the 6.1 version. I created a rails app in the following way

```
rails new book-gallery --api --mysql
```

The app created successfully. I proceeded next doing the following

```
rails g scaffold Author name:string country:string
```

This created the controller and model with the crud. But I want API to be versioned instead

Requirement:

```
/v1/authors
```

If I pass versioning on the scaffold, the model is also getting versioned which should not be

```
rails g scaffold v1/Author name:string country:string
```

The controller path is correct, but the model I got `v1.rb` and folder of name v1.

I don't need versioning in the model, I am trying to keep it as `author.rb`

Any guidance will be grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve what you want with 1 command.

You could do a scaffold_controller and create the model without scaffolding:

`rails g model Author name country`

`rails g scaffold_controller v1/Author`

You can also skip the `:string` for the model attributes. Without given the datatype it will set it to string by default.

Comment: Ya was trying with one command. This I have tried and it works.
Thank you for the string part. But issue with this approach is in controller it users V1 for fetching from database. Example `V1::Author.all`